# rpm reports dependency missing, but it is present?

Tags: centos, rpm, dependencies

I want to install this rpm (of course I can install it with `-nodeps` but I don't like this "solution").

```
LANG=C rpm -Uvh /home/pippiripi/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/oracle-fdw-27012018git-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm 
error: Failed dependencies:
    libclntsh.so.12.1()(64bit) is needed by oracle-fdw-27012018git-1.el7.centos.x86_64
```

Of course `libclntsh.so.12.1` is on the system:

```
ldconfig -p|grep libclntsh.so.12.1
    libclntsh.so.12.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1
```

And its rpm is installed:

```
rpm -qf /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1
oracle-instantclient12.2-basic-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64
```

The library is 64bit

```
 file /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1
/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=068dc0a57c8b0310180f2a659b71de4115ba9020, not stripped
```

Solution?

Comment: What happens if you run `rpm -q --provides oracle-instantclient12.2-basic`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem *appears* to be that the "instant client" package doesn't list the libraries as `Provides:` at all.

This has been depressingly common with proprietary packages but then, to be fair, it's not installing those libraries in the usual location, and it would in most cases be misleading to `Provides:` them anyway.

Your best solution is probably to disable automatic requires / provides processing in the `.spec` for your fdw package and manually add `Requires:` and `BuildRequires:` listing the "instant client" packages (>= whatever version you build against, I guess).

Answer (score 0):

the library that is installed on your system is the 32-bit version. You are trying to install a 64bit rpm (which you can see in the name: oracle-fdw-27012018git-1.el7.centos.**x86_64**.rpm ), which requires the 64bit version of the same library. The dependency is not simply libclntsh.so.12.1 but libclntsh.so.12.1()**(64bit)** .

so either find a 32bit version of oracle-fdw; either you should install the 64bit version of oracle-instantclient12.2-basic.

**EDIT** : you should search a package that provides **libclntsh.so.12.1()(64bit)**. Apparently your version of oracle-instantclient12.2-basic does not. To check on your system: `rpm -q --whatprovides "libclntsh.so.12.1()(64bit)"` which probably won't yield anything... so you have to search for an rpm that provides that. Best use a package manager such as `yum` or `zypper` who will manage those dependencies for you.

Comment: OP states in the question that `oracle-instantclient12.2-basic-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64` is installed.

Comment: @WillCrawford you are right, I appended more information in my answer on how to try to solve the problem.

Comment: The library is 64bit,I edit my question